# Are antes (or other dead money) counted toward the rake?

Tags: rake, antes

Let's say there's a 5% rake and no rake cap (just to keep this simple). Five players are dealt in. Each player posts $4 ante, one player posts some small blind, and another player posts some big blind. The first three players fold (as their first action), and then both the SB player and the BB player go all-in for $50. The pot contains 5 * $4 + 2 * $50 = $120 now.

Is the rake then $6 = 0.05 * $120, or is it $5 = 0.05 * $100. In other words, are the antes included in the rake calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's totally up to the casino and any applicable local laws. Generally speaking, yes, dead money counts, but uncalled bets do not. Many casinos have a minimum rake (maybe even zero) in the case of blind-steals.  Many also have a separate rake for jackpots, with different rules.

Answer (score 0):

yes. every place I have ever been. ante is a bet, like any other other antrs are calls, every called bet is part of the pot and subject to rake